# How can I (easily) format long intervals (over 30 days, but including time components)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, intervals

I am using a spreadsheet to record the intervals between certain medical events. Each event's timestamp is recorded in one column, so the interval between each event is the difference between consecutive cells (and the time since the last event uses now()).

First problem: I want to display the interval in days, hours and minutes. None of the built-in formats will do this, they report the days remaining after discarding complete months. So I am using this expression:

```
TEXT(TRUNC(C2-C1),"0") & " days " & TEXT(MOD(C2-C1,1),"hh "" hrs "" mm ""mins""")
```

which (e.g.) shows "46 days 13 hrs 44 mins". I was hoping there was a way to format a date/time value to show this rather than making the cell a string value, but I haven't been able to find one.

Second problem: I want to display the average value of all completed intervals in the same format. Because I can't average the string values produced by the previous expression I need to average the numeric equivalent (which I'd prefer not to have visible in the sheet) and then convert it to a string as for a single interval.

I can probably do this with a similar approach (if I don't run out of characters to enter the formula) but it seems to me that there must be a better way.

Ideally there is a solution which will work in Excel 2010. Has anyone solved a similar problem before and can give me some pointers?

Thanks, T

Edit: Some data to show what I am working with (I hope the image is readable). Here's a few lines from the sheet.

[image: Raw (unformatted) data]

The formula for H2 etc. is

```
=IF(G2="c",NOW()-C2,"")
```

I5 is calculated as the difference between C5 and C*prev* (where *prev* is chosen so that D5 and D*prev* are both set). Obvious extension of this for J and K.

M2, M3 and M4 are respectively

```
=AVERAGEIF(K5:(INDIRECT("K"&(ROWS(K:K)))),"<>0")
=AVERAGEIF(J5:(INDIRECT("J"&(ROWS(J:J)))),"<>0")
=AVERAGEIF(I5:(INDIRECT("I"&(ROWS(I:I)))),"<>0")
```

Now, I can use a custom format for the values in H, I and J, and for M3 and M4, because these values will never exceed a few days. But values in K and M2 will be somewhere around 100 so I can't just format the raw value.

With custom formatting applied:
[image]

Here K6 and M2 say "27 days.." not "87 days..". That's what I'd like to fix nicely, hopefully without populating additional cells or writing a 3gl function to do it.

Comment: Numberformat for days only has a range of `1-31`. To retain it as a number, you could use total hours and minutes; or you could return decimal days.

Comment: For the second part (the average) it might be better to go back to the original calculation if possible. Also bear in mind that if the times follow each other without any gaps the average interval is just (last time - first time)/(number of times - 1). Ideally would help contributors if you could show some (made-up) data and expected results.

Comment: @tom-sharpe I've provided some data above. It's probably obvious what device I'm monitoring here!

Comment: Thanks! The only thing I can come up with is to use a separate column for the days and for the hours and minutes when displaying the durations and averages. It isn't the easiest thing to work with though (you couldn't use Averageif any more for example) so I'm not offering it as an answer to your problem. Might be worth noting that just using average gives the same answer as averageif for your sample data (it ignores the blanks and headers)

Comment: If you can't get the display you want by formatting,  perhaps use two columns,  one (hidden?) with the raw data for use in calculations, the other with you text formula for display

Answer (score 1):

Date_Times in Excel are stored as days (with the decimal part representing parts of a day).
If the date matters, rather than just a number of days, then day zero is 1899/12/31.
Your first thought was right - do with formatting, not by turning a number into a string.
Entering date into A and time into B, with C=A+B is a good start, so that you can E.g. subtract one point in time from another without having to do anything about straddling midnight, month-ends etc, calculate averages etc.
Consolidating the comments already here: per https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-numbers-as-dates-or-times-418bd3fe-0577-47c8-8caa-b4d30c528309 you cannot get d for days above 31 (and it won't accept a format `0 hh:mm:ss` )
I suggest that you do all your calculations using just numbers to get to say column M, and in N2 put `=M2` etc, so you have the same values twice.
Then for formatting, use Format Cells | Number | Custom.
In column M put `0 "days"`.
In column N put `hh "hours" mm "minutes"`.

Comment: To maximise readability for others, I suggest that in column C you have leading zeroes for days and hours: dd/mm/yyy hh:mm (or if sharing internationally yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm)

Comment: Almost perfect, but formatting the value as '0 "days"' rounds the days and displays 88 not 87. I can put the real average in column N, and set column M to trunc(N) (or whatever formula strips the time off),  but is there a format that would do the same on the full value?

Comment: You are right. Sorry I missed that rounding. And your approach is also the only one that seems to work. The relevant formula (assuming all outputs are positive) in M2 is =int(N2)